# Spring Boot Tutorial - Error when trying to check service

Tags: spring-boot

I followed steps given in https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/ for building a springboot application. I am using intellij & Maven, Application started without any errors but when i tried to access hpp://localhost:8080. I am getting an error as below

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Aug 21 08:01:16 IST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: Did you get any exceptions in the log?

Comment: No i have not got any exceptions in log

Comment: start your app with `-Ddebug` vm option and see if there is more logging and errors generated. Maybe post the whole start up log here.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly likely that either the `@RestController` or `@RequestMapping` annotations are missing from your controller class.

You can compare you code to the completed example here, to see if there's anything missing:
https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot/blob/master/complete/src/main/java/hello/HelloController.java